# Convert β to odds ratio?

Tags: ratio, odds

I would like to convert β-values into odds ratios. It is about table 1 on page 5 in the article
„A revised inventory of Adverse Childhood Experiences“
https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/A-revised-inventory-of-Adverse-Childhood-Finkelhor-Shattuck/e8c839ac810be741ad4622916cb5726f4229c8ea
The methodology section of the article states:
„Psychological distress score was regressed on the predictor variables using OLS regression.“
Table 5 states:
„OLS regression of distress symptom score“ and the designation β.
Example: For the variable "Emotional abuse" in Model 1, the β-value 0.16 is given.
If I calculate EXP(0.16) in Excel, I get 1.17351087.
Is this the correct odds ratio? Or is there another way to calculate the odds ratio for this example using the data in the article?
Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Welcome to CV. Since you’re new here, you may want to take our [tour], which has information for new users. Why do you need odds ratios here? OLS results have a rather straightforward interpretation.

Comment: I would like to combine effect sizes from different studies for a meta-analysis. In many other studies odds ratios are given. Therefore, I would like to convert the effect sizes from the linked article into odds ratios if possible.

Comment: Welcome to cv, David! Could you give readers a better start into your question by stating the purpose as you did in your comment, and that it is about logistic regression (is that right?) - there are so many other statistical methods were different things are called "$\beta$".

Comment: Ute I can try to explain my concern with an example. In the first article already mentioned, the β-value is 0.16 for the association between emotional abuse and mental impairment. In the following second study
https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC6829158/pdf/Dtsch_Arztebl_Int-116_0635.pdf
in Table 2, the adjusted association between emotional abuse and mental impairment (depression) Odds ratio is 1.84. I would like to have these two effect sizes both as odds ratios so that they can be compared and summarized if necessary.

Comment: Ok, it is actually a case of logisic regression :) @T.E.G.'s comment refers to ordinary least squares regression, and is very natural, because the context was not given in your question.

Comment: @Ute because it asks about converting OLS coefficient to odds ratio (articles in the question and comment are different).

Comment: @T.E.G. Sorry, I should not have pinged you - it was exactly what I wanted to point out

Comment: It's not actually logistic. Table 1 in the article gives both OLS and negative binomial results. But it does NOT give the betas for the NB models, it gives the rate ratio.  Table 2 in the linked article is not results at all.

Comment: Please add new information as an edit to the post and not only as a comment. Comments can be deleted and are often onlky seen by few people.